# How to compare two dateTime in Xquery?

Tags: xquery

Lets say I have a two dates-

> 2017-11-17T06:04:17.138117-06:00 and 
>   2017-11-17T06:04:47.056091-06:00

How to compare these two ?

Answer (score 4):

Cast them as `xs:dateTime` and compare them using standard comparison operators:

```
xs:dateTime('2017-11-17T06:04:17.138117-06:00') < xs:dateTime('2017-11-17T06:04:47.056091-06:00')
```